# QWebView and downloading of pdf files on genome browser

Tags: qt, qwebview

I am working on a Qt project (Java). I am trying to build a qwebview that allows me to download pdf files from a website.

Here is the code I used:

```
public Browser() {
    this.setDefaultUrl();
    this.page().setForwardUnsupportedContent(true);
    this.page().unsupportedContent.connect(this,"download()");
}
public void setUrl(String url){
    this.load(new QUrl(url));
}
public void setDefaultUrl(){
    this.load(new QUrl("http://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgGateway"));
}
public void download(){
    System.out.println("Ok");
}
```

If I click on "We still provide postscript files: browser graphic and ideogram" the signal shoots correctly but if I click on "Download the current browser graphic in PDF" I don't get any signal. Is this because pdf files must be handled differently?
Any ideas why?
Thanks a lot in advance